# How to access and register onfocus event on an input element inside of an iframe that is being appended dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a legacy project where an `iframe` is being appended and has `input` elements in it. I want to register a `focus` event on the input elements in that iframe.

A basic recreation of the code is below. It has a `button` with id `addIframe` and when its clicked the desired iframe is being appended to a div with the id `iframeDiv`.

If anyone could help me with this that can be really helpful. Thank you.

```js
$('#addIframe').on('click', () => {
  $('#iframeDiv').append(`<iframe id="appendedIframe" src="http://localhost:8080/iframeDemo.html"></iframe>`)
})
```

Comment: Is the content of the iframe on the same domain as the parent window - right down to the `8080` port?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no its from another server.

Comment: Then what you're trying to do is not possible. You cannot interact with cross-domain content.